# Could someone translate this screenshot error message?

Tags: транслитерация

my mobile app facebook login review is rejected.
but the reject screenshot may written russian language (i’m not sure )
could someone translate it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In your situation, I would use some free online OCR tool (e.g. [img2txt.com](https://img2txt.com/en)) to recognize the text on the image, and then use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) to translate into English, or whatever your preferred language is. Here is what I've got for your message by following these steps: `The user does not have sufficient rights to view the application. : User cannot view this application due to developer settings.` Neat, huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ошибка 
У пользователя недостаточно прав для просмотра приложения.
Пользователь не может просматривать это приложение из-за настроек разработчика
```

->

```
Error
The user does not have sufficient rights to view the application.
User cannot view this app due to developer settings.
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)